# Oracle SQL-ALTER TABLE Error

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been looking over the following SQL code for awhile and just can't seem to find the problem. I'm relatively new to SQL, so I'm sure it's just something I'm overlooking. The error message I get is: ORA-01735: Invalid ALTER TABLE option.

Code:

```
ALTER TABLE PATIENT
(
ADD CONSTRAINT PProfileForeignKey
    FOREIGN KEY (pProfileID) REFERENCES PATIENT_PROFILE(Profile_ID),
ADD CONSTRAINT InsForeignKey
    FOREIGN KEY (pInsID) REFERENCES INSURANCE(Insurance_ID)
        ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

I have triple checked to make sure the foreign key column names and the referenced column names are correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Same error unfortunately.

Comment: Can you specify multiple Foreign Keys in a single `ALTER TABLE` statement? Try splitting it in two...

Comment: @dnoeth, I think that was the problem, thank you!

Comment: @dnoeth thanks ... wrong comment removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems The parentheses are in wrong place

```
ALTER TABLE PATIENT
 ADD (CONSTRAINT PProfileForeignKey
    FOREIGN KEY (pProfileID) REFERENCES PATIENT_PROFILE(Profile_ID),
    CONSTRAINT InsForeignKey
    FOREIGN KEY (pInsID) REFERENCES INSURANCE(Insurance_ID)
        ON DELETE SET NULL);
```

Comment: Correction, if you saw my first comment. This did work on another ALTER TABLE, I must have done something wrong the first time. Thank you!

Comment: @Zarch  thank you very much ... I was sure that would work